# How to remove text to text from string in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this string :

```
$body = '<a href="/title/tt2034800/?ref_=inth_ov_tt"> The Great Wall</a>';
```

And i want to remove :

```
?ref_=inth_ov_tt
```

From $body .

I test this code and didn't work :

```
$body = preg_replace('#ref_=(.*?)"#is', '', $body);
```

Comment: The regex works fine for me. Just add the `?` to remove exactly what you want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to the following:

```
$body = '<a href="/title/tt2034800/?ref_=inth_ov_tt"> The Great Wall</a>';
$body = preg_replace('#\?ref_=([^"]+)(?=")#i', '', $body);

print_r($body);
```

The output(as source code):

```
<a href="/title/tt2034800/"> The Great Wall</a>
```

Comment: Thanks . Worked Fine .